# Vatican spiral staircase

Tags: italy, rome, vatican-city

Can you view and photograph the spiral staircase at the Vatican for free. Or do you have to buy a ticket for the museum

Comment: According to https://www.journeystoitaly.com/bramante-staircase-in-the-vatican/ the Bramante staircase is closed to the general public, unless you buy a private visit ticket.

Comment: @Traveller That's the original one. The new one is open to the public.

Comment: It is quite a workout to reach the top and it is a bit narrow at times. There are paid elevators, but going by foot is free. On top, you have full view. It is definitely worth it if you can handle the hordes of people that just came for selfies.

Answer (score 12):

The Instagram-famous "[Snail Staircase](https://www.solitarywanderer.com/spiral-staircase-at-the-vatican-museum/)" below is inside the museum and requires a ticket.

[image]
[By © User:Colin / Wikimedia Commons, CC BY-SA 3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=22120484)

The original [Bramante Staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bramante_Staircase), which is older but (IMHO) less impressive, is only accessible on special tours.

Comment: Why do you consider the Bramante less impressive?

Comment: @Mast The new one is much more dramatic, just compare photos on the wiki page above.